# Finding upcoming birthdays with jOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date-arithmetic, jooq

I'm trying to convert an existing query which looks for upcoming birthdays to use jOOQ. My original query - using MySQL, and a bit simplified - is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM people 
WHERE
    DATE_ADD(people_dob, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(people_dob) YEAR) 
    BETWEEN CURDATE() and DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

I tried to express it using jOOQ but failed. I got as close as

```
context
    .selectCount()
    .from(PEOPLE)
    .where(
        PEOPLE_DOB.add(year(currentTimestamp()).minus(year(PEOPLE_DOB)))
        .between(currentTimestamp()).and(currentTimestamp().add(7)));
```

Unfortunately, that translates to

```
select count(*) 
from `people` 
where 
    date_add(`people`.`people_dob`, interval (extract(year from current_timestamp()) - extract(year from `people`.`people_dob`)) day) 
    between current_timestamp() and date_add(current_timestamp(), interval 7 day)
```

What breaks the query here is the `expr_unit` argument for [DATE_ADD][date_add], which is my original query is `YEAR`, but in the one rendered by jOOQ is `DAY`.

How can I translate this query into jOOQ? I don't care much about the current format, I just want to understand how to get the same result.

Answer (score 4):

jOOQ's [`Field.add()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#add%28org.jooq.Field%29) method is inspired by Oracle's interpretation of

```
DATE + NUMBER
```

... where `NUMBER` (if an `Integer` or `Double`) is a number of days. What you want is the equivalent of adding a SQL standard `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` to a given date. This could be achieved through using [jOOQ's `YearToMonth` interval type](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/types/YearToMonth.html), if you wanted to add a constant interval. The `YearToMonth` type also extends `java.lang.Number`, and can thus also be used with [`Field.add()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#add%28org.jooq.Field%29), intuitively.

While it might be possible to generate such a `Field<YearToMonth>` through existing jOOQ 3.2 API, I believe that you will be better off to just resort to plain SQL, possibly by creating a reusable method:

```
public static <T extends java.util.Date> 
Field<T> dateInCurrentYear(Field<T> field) {
    return DSL.field("DATE_ADD({0}, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR({0}) YEAR)",
                     field.getDataType(),
                     field);
}
```

This might be a useful feature addition for [#2727](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2727) as well...

Unfortunately, the various SQL dialects' interpretations of date time arithmetic is hard to standardise. We're constantly improving things there, but often, plain SQL is the best way to write dialect-specific date time arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving the issue is using a String in the where clause. I'm writing it down here for completeness, but I think it misses the point of jOOQ

```
context.
    selectCount().
    from(PEOPLE).
    where("DATE_ADD(people_dob, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(people_dob) YEAR)" + 
        " BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()").
```