# CASE Statement in jooq?

Tags: sql, database, casting, case, jooq

I am new in jooq So i want to write this below query in jooq  .

```
"CASE len(CAST(SUBSTRING(attachedblob, 1, 1) AS varchar(1))) when 1 then 'true' else 'false' end  ReviewExistance "
```

Can you tell me please .

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get stuck? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness' sake, here's how your SQL expression could translate to jOOQ:

```java
// Assuming a static import:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
import static org.jooq.impl.SQLDataTypes.*;

decode().value(
       length(
           cast(
               substring(MY_TABLE.ATTACHEDBLOB, 1, 1),
               VARCHAR.length(1)
           )
       )
   )
   .when(1, "true")
   .otherwise("false")
   .as("ReviewExistance");
```

If that's too nasty, you can always resort to plain SQL. Examples are given here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860383/521799
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20728037/521799

Comment: Hi how to create selectQuery.addSelect(Routines.fGetdocketeventpeopledetail(Folder.FOLDER.FOLDER_RSN, 2, 2).as("Party2")); function. because in our case this funtion parameter first one field then two agrument int, how can create this function in jooq

Comment: @Himanshu: Can you please ask a new question on Stack Overflow? It will be hard to answer in comments of an unrelated question...