# Group by calendar week in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, datetime, jooq

I use this field in GROUP BY to get monthly reports:

```
trunc(date(SOME_TIMESTAMP), DatePart.MONTH).as("month")
```

Also works the same way for daily or yearly reports.

But how can I do weekly reports? There is no `DatePart.WEEK`.

Answer (score 2):

you could try a plain SQL,like this:

```
public static Field<Integer> yearWeek(Field<Timestamp> field, int mode) {
    return DSL.field("yearweek({0}, {1})", SQLDataType.INTEGER,
            field, DSL.inline(mode));
}
```

use it like this:
`groupBy(yearWeek(SOME_TIMESTAMP_FIELD, 1))`.

the mode is recording to mysql's [yearweek](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_yearweek.asp).

Answer (score 1):

As of jOOQ 3.3, only SQL standard "date parts" are supported. There is a [pending feature request issue #2132](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2132) for adding other, vendor-specific date parts. In the mean time, you will probably need to resort to a plain SQL implementation, instead.

Some pointers here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860383/521799
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20728037/521799